# Sensei LMS Wordpress. Page My courses don´t detect login user

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a 2FA verification plugin for WordPress which works fine on many sites, but when I install it on a site where they have Sensei LMS, it doesn’t work.

The plugin performs the entire process, through Wp-login hooks, and when the verification process is finished, it logs the user in WordPress, but despite being logged in WordPress, when accessing the page my courses, it asks for a username and password. To any of the other pages, if you access and verify that you are correctly logged in.

It is as if sensei did not see that this user was already logged in when entering my courses.

Maybe you have to add a function, or a hook to inform sensei that the user has logged in?

I hope you can give me some clue on how to make sure that when logging in through a custom function in wordpress, I also login in senseo

Greetings

I hope you can give me some clue on how to make sure that when logging in through a custom function in wordpress, I also login in senseo

Greetings